# How can I combine the output (a single record) of these 3 SQL queries in a single output record?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem (I am using MySql).

I have to integrate the output of 3 queries into a single record in the following way.

I have these 3 queries:

**QUERY 1:**

```
select id_1, field_1.1, field_1.2,............., field_1.n where id=1;
```

Returning a **single record** containing something like:

```
field_1.1, field_1.2,...............,field_1.n
```

**QUERY 2 (used to obtain a username):**

```
select value from settings where setting_name = 'username';
```

it will always return a single record like:

```
my_username
```

**3) (used to obtain a password):**

```
select value from settings where setting_name = 'password';
```

it will always return a single record like:

```
my_password
```

I have to create a single query that combine the output of these 3 queries in a single output record, something like this:

```
field_1.1, field_1.2,...............,field_1.n, my_username, my_password
```

As you can see it starts with the value of the single record returned from the query 1, followed by the single value returned by the query 2 followed by the single value returned by the query 3.

How can I do something like this using SQL?

Comment: Please don't post the same question(s) twice, and ask just one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use query 2 and 3 and subqueries in the select of query 1:

```
select id_1, 
       field_1.1, 
       field_1.2,............., field_1.n,
      (select value from settings where setting_name = 'username') as my_username, --Query2
      (select value from settings where setting_name = 'password') as my_password  --Query3
from  table
where id=1;
```

Comment: what if the subquery returns more than one record?

Comment: @Rahul OP specifically says it returns one record for both.

Comment: @Rahul it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the `JOIN` syntax, you can do something like this:

```
select 
  t.id_1, t.field_1.1, t.field_1.2,............., t.field_1.n, 
  s1.`value` as as my_username, 
  s2.`value` as as my_password 
from  table1 t
join settings s1 on (s1.setting_name = 'username')
join settings s2 on (s2.setting_name = 'password')
where t.id=1;
```

Note, that `value` is a reserved keyword, you have to escape like `value`. I also had to prefix your original table fields to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

try this please...

```
select id_1, field_1.1, field_1.2,.., field_1.n, u.username, p.password 
from <table 1>
left join
(select value as username from settings where setting_name = 'username') u
on (1=1)
left join
(select value as password from settings where setting_name = 'password') p
on (1=1)
where id=1
```